# Grav/Twig looping array

Tags: php, content-management-system, twig, grav

I have a simple problem with my Grav/Twig template. I have a .md file that is structured like so...

```
---
class: news
title: Latest News
story:
  title: TITLE OF STORY
  date:
    month: April
    day: 2
    year: 2016
  highlights:
    points:
      - icon: mic.png
        text: Best Speaker Award
      - icon: trophy.png
        text: Winner as voted by audience
  quote: 
    text: “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur dictum nisl quis pharetra dictum. Etiam ac egestas leo. Pellentesque tincidunt sem vel risus vehicula scelerisque. Cras rutrum, mauris viverra porttitor condimentum, orci quam condimentum libero, ac tempor nunc risus ac felis.”
    author: -Time Magazine
  cite: http://www.time.com
  image: awards.jpg
---
```

I want to pull the icon: mic.png and icon: trophy.png values out and do something like this in my news.twig.html file...

```
<div class="highlights">
    {% for highlight in page.header.story.highlights.points %}
      <div class="point">
        {% if highlight.text %}
        <span class="highlight-icon">              
          <img src="{{ page.media.images.[ {{ highlight.icon }} ].url }}">
        </span>
        {% endif %}
        {% if highlight.text %}
        <span class="highlight-text">{{ highlight.text }}</span>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

But I am getting an error, "Expected name or number" on the line with the img tag,

```
<img src="{{ page.media.images.[ {{ highlight.icon }} ].url }}">
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this same problem in the future here was my answer... I changed the  line to this...

```
<img src="{{ page.find('/images').media[highlight.icon].url }}">
```

Comment: It's important to note that while accessing a property with a space it should be referenced as (for example) page.taxonomy['dark colors'][0] while without the space it should be referenced as page.taxonomy.colors[0]